# How to put lat, lon value in url from csv file during reversegecoding

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a URL similar to this: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=17.978733&lon=79.14550876&zoom=14&addressdetails=1 and
I want to change the `lat` and `lon` values in my csv file.

```
import csv 
import requests 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

def loadxml(): 

    # url of rss feed 
    url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=25.6&lon=78.0176&zoom=14&addressdetails=1'

    # creating HTTP response object from given url 
    resp = requests.get(url) 

    # saving the xml file 
    with open('ldn.xml', 'wb') as f: 
        f.write(resp.content) 

loadxml()
```

This is command is for a single `lat` `lon` but I want my csv's `lat` and `lon` values.

Answer (score 0):

The new url can be created as follows:

```
def get_url(lat,lon):
    return 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat='+str(lat)+'&lon='+str(lon)'&zoom=14&addressdetails=1
```

Suppose your dataframe is called as df and the columns that contains latitude and longitude have the names lat and lon respectively, follows this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    url = get_url(row[lat],row[lon])

    resp = requests.get(url) 


    with open('ldn.xml', 'wb') as f: 
        f.write(resp.content)
```

Hope this can help you.